# Direct output to syslog from upstart

Tags: linux, shell, logging, ubuntu-14.04, upstart

With the changes to `/dev/kmsg` in Ubuntu 14.04 I'm not sure of a clean way to direct STDOUT/STDERR from an upstart script into the syslog. Formerly the script would look like this:

```
script
  exec &> /dev/kmsg
  cd /var/www/app
  exec bin/puma -C config/puma.rb
end script
```

I found a fairly viable alternative in piping within the exec line:

```
script
  cd /var/www/app
  exec bin/puma -C config/puma.rb | logger -t puma
end script
```

That achieves the exact result I want, but it leaves upstart with the wrong PID. Instead of the PID for the process I want (puma) it has the PID of logger instead.

So far I've tried modifying the `exec &>` call to pipe instead:

```
exec 2>&1 | logger
exec -| logger
exec |& logger
```

Is there a syntactical variant I'm missing? Is there a different descriptor I can direct into? Thanks!

Comment: My primary reference has been http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: Would logging to a file and configuring syslog to read that file be a viable option?

Comment: It would, but I'm mostly curious if this is really possible. I don't see the difference between exec directing to a fd versus directing to a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricky but working example of how to accomplish this on serverfault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/114052/logging-a-daemons-output-with-upstart